# how to get selected text in any application after mouse up

Tags: delphi, winapi, text, vcl, selected

i'm working in a vcl application in rad studio x10 .
I need some help to add a functionnality to my application .
I need a way or code win32 to get selected text in any application such a browser or a text editor and trigger my application after the mouse up.
is there any way to do it ? 
thank you.

Comment: I swear I've seen a question exactly like this a couple years ago.....

Comment: That is impossible in full generality. Cannot for done for arbitrary applications.